# Why the degree of a proper map is well defined?

Tags: algebraic-topology, smooth-manifolds

Consider a proper map $f:M=\mathbb{R}^n\to N=\mathbb{R}^n$, we define the degree of it as followes.

Choose $\omega\in H_c^n(N)$, then we define $\int_Mf^*\omega=\deg f\int_N\omega$ where $f^*$ means pullback.

I don't know why this is well defined. Moreover, if we consider

[image]

Then this seems right. But if $f$ is not surjective, then we let $V=N-\mathrm{Im}f$. If we have two forms $\mathrm{supp}\alpha\subset V,\mathbb{supp}\beta\subset\mathrm{Im}f$ with $\int\alpha=\int\beta=1$, then
$$\int f^*(\alpha-\beta)=\int f^*\alpha-\int f^*\beta=-\int f^*\beta\neq0,$$
but $\int(\alpha-\beta)=0$, so we should have
$$\int f^*(\alpha-\beta)=\deg f\int(\alpha-\beta)=0,$$
which is impossible.

---

Add:

More percisely, this means $\deg f=0$ since $\int f^*\beta=0$, but I still don't know that why this is well defined?

Comment: The theorem you’re lacking is that $H^n_c(\mathbb{R}^n)$ is always one-dimensional, and the integral is an isomorphism from that space to $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: @Mindlack Thanks, I know logically that the commutative diagram forces $\deg f=0$, but I don't know why the proper map $f$ send $\int\beta$ to zero intuitively.

Comment: I’m not sure there’s much of an intuition of this rather than a fact, a nontrivial one. Another way you can perhaps see it is that the non-surjectivity forces the function to have varying orientations on the same fiber, and everything averages out.